# Set length parameter based on KOMA \ifthispageodd

Tags: koma-script, expansion, geometry, lengths

### Background

I'm using scrrept and titlesec (changing from titlesec to pure koma is on my todo list) any I've redefined `\chapter` to be a full page affair. The issue is when I'm using `twosided`.

#### Situation

My code includes `\begin{minipage}[t]{8.2cm-\leftmargin}`. However, when using `twosided` this means that only odd page's content is correctly positioned.
I have tried changing this to the form `\begin{minipage}[t]{8.2cm-\ifthispageodd{\leftmargin}{\rightmargin}}`.

#### Issue

Unfortunately, this seems to have caused my compilation to hang (on 100% CPU usage though) at the final stage. See last log line below

```
Overfull \hbox (162.18062pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 156--156
| [] |
[12] (./demo.aux)
```

#### Thoughts so far

I'm guessing something like `\expandafter` is what I want (tried that before `ifthispageodd`, didn't work) but I don't know enough to get this to work.

### Ideal Solution

Ideally, I'd actually use `\newgeometry` and fixed margins for the chapter pages to save me all of this accounting-for-changing-margins hassle. However, I couldn't get that to work without adding an extra page.

## The Code

#### Relevant Section

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {}
    {\titleBackground\thispagestyle{empty}}
    {4pt}
    {
        \begin{minipage}[t]{8.2cm-\ifthispageodd{\leftmargin}{\rightmargin}}

            \mbox{}\\
            \null\hfill\fontsize{6.5cm}{1ex}\selectfont{\ifbool{optionSolid}{\color{page}}{\color{primary}}\thechapter}
        \end{minipage}
        \hspace*{-5mm}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{\paperwidth-7cm-\ifthispageodd{\leftmargin}{\rightmargin}}
            \mbox{}\\
            \vspace*{-1.1cm}
            \begin{flushleft}
                \begin{spacing}{5}
                    \fontsize{1.7cm}{1em}
                    \fontseries{tx}
                    \selectfont
                    \ifbool{optionDark}{
                        \color{primaryVarient}
                    }{
                        \color{alternativePrimary}
                    }
    }[\end{spacing}\end{flushleft}\end{minipage}]

\titleformat{name=\chapter, numberless}[display]
    {}
    {\titleBackground\thispagestyle{empty}}
    {0pt}
    {
        \fontsize{2cm}{1em}
    }

}
```

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newbool{optionDark}
\newbool{optionSolid}

\definecolor{page}{HTML}{FFFFFF} % white
\definecolor{text}{HTML}{000000} % black
\definecolor{primary}{HTML}{019875} % emerald
\definecolor{primaryVarient}{HTML}{1CBE77} % emerald mixed with lighter green
\definecolor{alternativePrimary}{HTML}{13293D} % blue

\setlength{\leftmargin}{1.5cm}
\setlength{\rightmargin}{2cm}

% \makeatletter
% Chapter format
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {}
    {\thispagestyle{empty}}
    {4pt}
    {
        \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr.2cm-\ifthispageodd{\leftmargin}{\rightmargin}\relax}
            \mbox{}\\
            \null\hfill\fontsize{6.5cm}{1ex}\selectfont{\ifbool{optionSolid}{\color{page}}{\color{primary}}\thechapter}
        \end{minipage}
        \hspace*{-5mm}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\paperwidth-7cm-\ifthispageodd{\leftmargin}{\rightmargin}\relax}
            \mbox{}\\
            \vspace*{-1.1cm}
            \begin{flushleft}
                \begin{spacing}{5}
                    \fontsize{1.7cm}{1em}
                    \fontseries{tx}
                    \selectfont
                    \ifbool{optionDark}{
                        \color{primaryVarient}
                    }{
                        \color{alternativePrimary}
                    }
    }[\end{spacing}\end{flushleft}\end{minipage}]

\titleformat{name=\chapter, numberless}[display]
    {}
    {\thispagestyle{empty}}
    {0pt}
    {
        \fontsize{2cm}{1em}
    }

% \makeatother

\begin{document}

\newpage

\chapter{Demo Chapter}

\end{document}
```

#### Other Relevent Code

This is extracted from a class that I'm in the process of writing, which can be found here: https://github.com/tecosaur/bmc

Comment: You can't use `\ifthispageodd` there as it is not expandable. You need to use `\ifthispageodd{\begin{minipage}{8.2cm-\leftmargin}}{\begin{minipage}{8.2cm-\rightmargin}}`.

Comment: Off-topic: Have you seen the warnings about using `titlesec` with `scrreprt`? We already have several questions about defining headings with KOMA-Script commands instead of `titlesec`. Please have a look at them.

Comment: @Schweinebacke first paragraph of question: "*changing from titlesec to pure koma is on my todo list*"

Comment: @Schweinebacke I'm in the process but I have some issues that need to be worked out

Comment: AFAIK `\leftmargin` and `\rightmargin` are used for lists (and not for the page layout).

Comment: @esdd I defined them for use in my class, but if they're used for something common (as it sounds like they may be) I'll change them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, `\ifthispageodd` is not expandable and can't be used inside of a `\dimexpr` therefore. The solution is to use `\ifthispageodd` outside of the `\dimexpr`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newbool{optionDark}
\newbool{optionSolid}

\definecolor{page}{HTML}{FFFFFF} % white
\definecolor{text}{HTML}{000000} % black
\definecolor{primary}{HTML}{019875} % emerald
\definecolor{primaryVarient}{HTML}{1CBE77} % emerald mixed with lighter green
\definecolor{alternativePrimary}{HTML}{13293D} % blue

\setlength{\leftmargin}{1.5cm}
\setlength{\rightmargin}{2cm}

% \makeatletter
% Chapter format
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {}
    {\thispagestyle{empty}}
    {4pt}
    {%
      \ifthispageodd
        {\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr.2cm-\leftmargin\relax}}
        {\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr.2cm-\rightmargin\relax}}
            \mbox{}\\
            \null\hfill\fontsize{6.5cm}{1ex}\selectfont{\ifbool{optionSolid}{\color{page}}{\color{primary}}\thechapter}
        \end{minipage}
        \hspace*{-5mm}
        \ifthispageodd
          {\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\paperwidth-7cm-\leftmargin\relax}}
          {\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\paperwidth-7cm-\rightmargin\relax}}
            \mbox{}\\
            \vspace*{-1.1cm}
            \begin{flushleft}
                \begin{spacing}{5}
                    \fontsize{1.7cm}{1em}
                    \fontseries{tx}
                    \selectfont
                    \ifbool{optionDark}{
                        \color{primaryVarient}
                    }{
                        \color{alternativePrimary}
                    }
    }[\end{spacing}\end{flushleft}\end{minipage}]

\titleformat{name=\chapter, numberless}[display]
    {}
    {\thispagestyle{empty}}
    {0pt}
    {%
        \fontsize{2cm}{1em}
    }

% \makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Demo Chapter}

\end{document}
```